# How can I place a marker on each provinces of a country in jqvmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="vmap" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
            map: 'iran_ir',
            enableZoom: false,
            showTooltip: true,
            borderColor: '#FFF',
            hoverColor: '#1A3B4C',
            backgroundColor: '#add136',
            borderWidth: 3,
            borderColor: '#B0CE4A',
            borderOpacity: 1,
            color: '#112834',
            //pins: {},
            pinMode: 'content'
         });
     });
```

I think I should use `pins` property, but I don't know how to do that?!

Comment: you did not add dependencies I think that is a reason it did not work.

Comment: What dependency?!

Comment: provinence means to capital state or city or every state or city of world

Comment: I think they are not providing features to going deep as province level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `jqvmap` documentation, there isn't any way for that.

> pins { "pk" : "pk_pin_metadata", "ru" : "ru_pin_metadata", ... }
>
> This option defines pins, which will be placed on the regions. **The JSON can
> have only one element against one country code.** Elements should be
> strings containing the HTML or id of the pin (depends on the 'pinMode'
> option explained next).

I open an issue in GitHub for this feature.